# I cannot connect my cluster with mongo shell (mongo is not recognize)?

Tags: python

I'm learning MongoDB and I completed all the installation stuff and everything but I can not connect my cluster with mongo shell. can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: You need to add mongo executable to your PATH.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error (what is in the image now) in your text, and format that as `code`.